# Yii2 Basic reset password

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm trying to create a "Forgot your password" in Yii2 Basic

my function in controller is :

```
public function actionLostpassword() 
        {
            $model = new Userlogin;

            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) 
            {
                if (Userlogin::findOne(['UserEmail' => $model->TheEmeil]))
                { 
                    $this->ResetPassWords($model->TheEmeil); 
                } 
                else { 
                    echo "Email Not Match" ;
                }
            }
            else{
                return $this->render('Forms/_ForgetPassword', [
                        'model' => $model,
                    ]);
            }
        }

    public function ResetPassWords($temail)
        {
            $randPassword = Yii::$app->params['RandPassword'];

            $modd = Userlogin::findOne(['UserEmail' => $temail ]);
            $modd->Password = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($randPassword);
            $modd->save();
            echo $randPassword;
        }
```

My View is :

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'TheEmeil')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Reset' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

but if I use $modd->save(false); If I use false in $modd->save() the password change. is it possible to update password without using false ? because false it's mean Yii will not validate .

I used $modd->save(); $modd->getErrors(); I get blank page ; if i use var_dump ($model->TheEmeil); die; i get :

```
I:\zzerver\Uwamp -port 84\uw-cms-p8585\www\yii60\wfp\controllers\UsrslogController.php:129:string 'us2@ts.ts' (length=9)
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible - you should define correct validation rules in your model. Checking what is in `$modd->getErrors()` after `$modd->save()` will give you some hints what is wrong.

Comment: I did update to my question to insert what i get after $modd->getErrors()

Comment: Maybe offtopic, but I suggest you to take this functionality from `yii2-advanced` template

Answer (score 2):

When password is saved it should be validated. You can do:

1. create a virtual field called plainPassword
2. on setting plainPassword, set password to the encrypted version of plainPassword
3. adjust validation rules to run validation on plainPassword (there's nothing special to validate about the encrypted password anyway :) )

However I do not recommend having this logic in the ActiveRecord entity. 
It would be better for you to create a model like `ForgotPasswordForm extends Model`.

you should end up with something like this:

```
class UserLogin extends ActiveRecord {
  public $plainPassword;

  public function setPlainPassword($value){
    $this->password = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($value);
  }

  public function rules(){
    return [
      ['plainPassword', 'required', 'min' => 6]
    ];
  }

}
```